# How to stop Storyboard animation applied to ListBoxItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

In my chat application I'm having a listbox of users in which whoever sends a message and if his chat window is not open at user's side then his name starts blinking in listbox to notify user of incoming message.
I am removing animation if the user selects that sender.But animation stops only for the element to which animation applied last.

Below is the code I am using for applying animation to listboxItem,

```
   private void BlinkSenderUsername(int index, string userRole)
    {
        blinkAnimation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        blinkAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(1, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0))));
        blinkAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(0, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))));
        ListBoxItem target = new ListBoxItem();

    target = OnlineUserList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListBoxItem;
        OnlineUserList.ScrollIntoView(target);

        blinkStoryboard = new Storyboard
        {
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(900),
            RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
        };

        Storyboard.SetTarget(blinkAnimation, target);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(blinkAnimation, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));

        blinkStoryboard.Children.Add(blinkAnimation);
        blinkStoryboard.Begin(target, true);
    }
```

and on selection changed event of listbox(to stop animation on selection):

```
   private void OnlineUserListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    ListBoxItem listBoxItem = OnlineUserList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(OnlineUserList.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
                if (listBoxItem != null && listBoxItem.HasAnimatedProperties)
                {
                    blinkStoryboard.Stop(listBoxItem);
                }
```

}

Can anyone suggest, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**(according to Jai's answer):-

```
    static void MyClassStaticConstructor()
    {
        BlinkAnimation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        BlinkAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(1, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0))));
        BlinkAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(0, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))));

        BlinkStoryboard = new Storyboard
        {
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(900),
            RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
        };

        BlinkStoryboard.Children.Add(BlinkAnimation);
    }

    private void BlinkSenderUsername(int index, string userRole)
    {
        // There is no need to instantiate a ListBoxItem
        //ListBoxItem target = new ListBoxItem();
          ListBoxItem target = OnlineUserList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListBoxItem;

        if (target == null) return;
        MyClassStaticConstructor();
        Storyboard.SetTarget(BlinkAnimation, target);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(BlinkAnimation, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));

        BlinkStoryboard.Begin(target, true);
    }
```

and in selectionchanged event of listbox:

```
    private void OnlineUserListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
ListBoxItem listBoxItem = OnlineUserList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(OnlineUserList.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
            if (listBoxItem != null && listBoxItem.HasAnimatedProperties)
            {
                BlinkStoryboard.Stop(listBoxItem);
            }}
```

Comment: What does "But animatation stops for all other listboxitem except the element to which animation applied first." means?

Comment: I am able to stop animation for all the other Senders on selection but except for the SenderName to which animation applied for the very first time (i.e. suppose  user gets message from UserA then his name starts blinking and againg user receives a message from UserB(starts blinking), if i Click UserB then animation stops but if i click UserA it continues to blink. ). Is it clear now?

Comment: Debug code again and got to realize that animation stops only for the element to which it is applied last.

Comment: Your `blinkStoryboard` is a global field right? It is keeping reference of the last animation you set because you are "newing" it every time you set it.

Comment: @Jai yes it is globally declared field because i want to access it in selection changed Event of listbox to stop animation of listboxItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that for each `ListBoxItem`, you are creating one `Storyboard` and one `Animation` object. Both the storyboard and animation objects are saved to a single global field. When you set multiple of such animations, your global fields would have the references of **only** the animation/storyboard that are added last.

Change the implementation to this:

```
private static readonly DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BlinkAnimation;
private static readonly Storyboard BlinkStoryboard;

static MyClassStaticConstructor()
{
    BlinkAnimation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
    BlinkAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(1, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0))));
    BlinkAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(0, KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))));

    BlinkStoryboard = new Storyboard
    {
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(900),
        RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever,
    };

    BlinkStoryboard.Children.Add(blinkAnimation);
}

private void BlinkSenderUsername(int index, string userRole)
{
    // There is no need to instantiate a ListBoxItem
    //ListBoxItem target = new ListBoxItem();
    ListBoxItem target = OnlineUserList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListBoxItem;

    if (target == null) return; // Just make sure we managed to get a ListBoxItem instance
    OnlineUserList.ScrollIntoView(target);

    Storyboard.SetTarget(BlinkAnimation, target);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(BlinkAnimation, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));

    BlinkStoryboard.Begin(target, true);
}
```

Animations and Storyboards objects are reusable - so if multiple controls need the same animation, they can use the same animation/storyboard instances. You just need to instantiate it once. In my answer I have made them static, but you have the choice not make them static.

Comment: I was having Null reference exception so called MyClassStaticConstructor() just above Storyboard.SetTarget(BlinkAnimation, target); But the issue is still the same; animation stops only for last item

Comment: Thank u so much for the solution Jai. It is finally working the way i wanted. You saved my day. Thanks a lot buddy. :)